# How to edit cursor from a css ::first-letter element?

Tags: html, css, hover, mouse-cursor

I have not customized my site mouse cursor in anyway, so it is all as default. As such, all text when hovered have the cursor change into the "text select cursor" (this guy > ꕯ). Fine. I then styled my first letters (just changed color), and now they (the first letters) have the default arrow cursor when hovered. I then tried manually setting a cursor but the css rule is seemingly being ignored...

I styled the letters with this simple css rule:

```css
::first-letter{
    color: red;
}
```

I then tried setting a new cursor rule to it, and it did not work, even when setting it to none the arrow cursor still appear on it.

```css
::first-letter{
    cursor: none;
    color: red;
}
```

This is not about selecting text, or the blinking cursor from input text fields. It is simple the mouse cursor visually changing when above text.

Comment: While you can't change the cursor setting in first-letter pseudo-element, the quirk (of it changing to arrow) seems only to occur in Chrome/Edge at least on Windows 10. Firefox and IE11 both maintain the 'upright' cursor until you move to the left of the first character (ie out of the text). I can't see there's anything you can do to force it not to change on Chrome/Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter):

> Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used with the ::first-letter pseudo-element

`cursor` is not one of them.

Comment: That sucks as it is such a simple thing... At least seems like I can set the parent (the <p>) and that style applies just fine to the whole text and the first-letter.